# django - Unable to set delimiter in raw sql (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, django, migration

I want to define a stored procedure by a migration. Before this I'm trying to set delimiter but getting `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$' at line 1")`

Code:

```
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('...', '...'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL("DELIMITER $$"),
        # ...
        migrations.RunSQL("DELIMITER ;"),
    ]
```

I've found [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864156/alembic-wont-execute-raw-sql-that-sets-delimiter#comment102272190_49864156) about `DELIMITER` is a client keyword which might be not supported by specific tool but what is the right way in django?

Comment: DELIMITER is **not** SQL statement type. This is client command. read the manual for Django and search how to redefine default statements delimiter.

Comment: @Akina it depends on the underlying mysql connector, not on django, as the connector is the mysql client.

Comment: I would simply pass the create procedure statement with the entire body and the closing end without delimiter to runsql.

Comment: @Shadow, thx, it worked. But why do examples contain delimiter redefining?

Comment: Because most examples use mysql cli, which requires and recognises delimiter command.

Comment: @Shadow, I mean what's the point of using it if it worked without it?

Comment: Because not all clients work without it.

Comment: @Shadow, got it. Post the answer pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting delimiter wasn't needed. I just removed these rows and it worked.
(see post comments)